# open sqlite file with my application through intent-filter

Tags: android, sqlite, mime-types, intentfilter

I am trying to open a sqlite file through intent-filter declared
in my manifest.

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/ico"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:host="*" 
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.sqlite"
  />
</intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

When I try to open the sqlite file with a filemanager no apps shows  up.
I have tried changing mimetype but nothing seems to works.
Has anyone else had better luck?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I live in Brazil. sorry for the English. intent-filter in the second try:

```
       <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.fileName" />
```

Comment: with sqlite extensions it doesn't work. Does it work for you?